# MatchMedia event not firing on browser resize

Tags: javascript, function, media-queries

I am using MatchMedia to fire a function when a media query is matched, but for some reason it's not firing.

I have to reload the page to see the desired effect.

I don't see where I am going wrong.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1055px)").matches) {      
    var butterBarStyles = 'position:fixed;width:100%;background-color:#5a5a5a;' +
    'margin:0; left:0; top:0; z-index:1000;text-align:left;color:#fff;display:block;padding:4px;text-align:center;';
   }
 }, false);
```

Comment: Does the browser you are testing on support the match media function? - Also, you might want to consider using a [throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for the resize function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you please show us actually where butterBarStyles will asssign to what (element)..??

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara the link I posted has all the explanation needed. It even has an example.

Comment: @evolutionxbox where is the link.?

Comment: Sorry @HimeshAadeshara. The link (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is in the word "throttle".